# Como marcar/desmarcar checkboxes por coluna usando JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, checkbox

Aqui na empresa estamos fazendo uma gestão de plantas. Os apartamentos/unidades que tem final igual (por exemplo, Apto 1, Apto 11, Apto 21) e por ai vai, ficam uma embaixo da outra na construção e por esse motivo a planta vinculada a elas é a mesma, mas se um cliente pedir personalização em sua unidade, a planta padrão das outras precisa ser a mesma da personalização. Poderíamos apenas usar um `UPDATE` na tabela mas estou fazendo como me foi pedido e como nos foi pedido pelas construtoras até porque pode ser que a personalização acabe sendo feita apenas na unidade comprada pelo cliente e de acordo com o que ele requisitou mas se a empresa decidir mudar todas as plantas para que a padrão seja a mesma da personalizada, precisamos selecionar todas daquela coluna pra vincular. 
Cada prédio contém uma quantidade diferente de unidades por andar, alguns contém 4, outros 5 e por ai vai, então a quantidade de colunas retornadas na tabela, pode variar. No momento, estamos usando apenas uma função para selecionar todas as unidades ou nenhuma unidade mas eu queria saber, como dá pra modificar a minha função para selecionar ou desmarcar as unidades de apenas uma coluna.

A função é

```
<script>
    function marcardesmarcar(status){
     $(".chk").each(
            function(){
              if ($(".chk").prop("checked")) 
              $(this).prop("checked", status);
              else $(this).prop("checked", status);               
            }
       );
    }

           </script>'
```

E o método para aparecer os checkboxes para cada unidade é

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        if ($nome_torre_old != $row['nome_torre'] OR 
            $nome_bloco_old != $row['nome_bloco'] OR
            $andar_old      != $row['andar']) {
            echo '</tr><tr>';
            $nome_torre_old = $row['nome_torre'];
            $nome_bloco_old = $row['nome_bloco'];
            $andar_old      = $row['andar'];
        }
        echo '<td>      
            <input class="chk" style="margin-left:20px;" type="checkbox" id="p'.$row['id'].'" name="p'.$row['id'].'" ';
        if ($row['plt_uni_in_id_unidade']== $row['id'] AND $row['plt_uni_in_id_planta'] == $id_work) echo 'checked="checked"';
        echo ' />'.$row['nome_torre'].' '.$row['nome_bloco'].' '.$row['nome_apto'].'</td>';
    }
```

Aqui a imagem de como fica, nesse caso, o prédio possui 4 unidades por andar e mostra 4 colunas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então queria saber se tem alguma forma de ao inserir a opção de marcar/desmarcar no cabeçalho de cada coluna, conseguir marcar/desmarcar as opções que estão nela. Das formas que pensei, preciso saber previamente quantas colunas serão exibidas na tabela mas como eu disse, cada prédio tem uma quantidade diferente de unidades por andar então a quantidade de colunas irá variar.
Desculpem pela pergunta imensa mas quis explicar algumas coisas pra evitar respostas que não me servirão.

Comment: O que você quer é quando for selecionar, selecione apenas todos de uma torre?

Comment: Entendi conforme a pergunta do André Baill. Acho que quer apenas selecionar todos de um determinado bloco. O que torna confuso é a  introdução referente ao modelo de negócios. Evite postar algo muito específico. Poste algo genérico com dados fictícios, até mesmo por questão de privacidade. Bastava apenas postar esse último texto que está após a imagem.

Comment: O apto 1 fica embaixo do 11 que fica embaixo do 21 e por ai vai 
Isso quer dizer que a planta de todo Apto 1, 11, 21, 31 da Torre Sul E Norte serão iguais. Mas quando um cara vai lá e compra uma unidade na planta e fala "Olha, quero que tira um quarto e faça escritorio" a empresa pode alterar só a planta da unidade que o cliente comprou ou a de todas as unidades que estão acima e abaixo e as unidades do mesmo num do outro bloco/torre ficarão iguais porque tem que seguir padrão.

Comment: Tipo, é só olhar a imagem que eu postei da tabela e falar como faço pra selecionar só por coluna, sendo que a quantidade de colunas pode variar de acordo com a quantidade de unidades por andar, ou seja eu não tenho como saber se a tabela vai ter 2/3/4/5/6 colunas mas preciso selecionar POR coluna.

Answer (score 2):

Seria isso?

```
$(function(){
    $("table tr").each(function(){
        $(this).find("td").eq(<aqui passa o indice da coluna>).find("input").attr("checked", "checked");
    }); 
});
```

```js
$(function(){
    $("table tr").each(function(){
        $(this).find("td").eq(1).find("input").attr("checked", "checked");
    }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Coluna 1</td>
    <td>Coluna 2</td>
    <td>Coluna 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Existem várias soluções possíveis.
Eis uma delas usando os dados que você deixou no código

```
<?php
$cols = 4; // Quantidade de unidades por bloco ou por andar

$rows = array();
// Gerando dados ficticios
$id = 1;
for ( $andar = 1; $andar < 6; $andar++) { // Torre Norte
    for ( $unidade = ($andar * 100) + 1; $unidade < ($andar * 100) + 5; $unidade ++) {
        $rows[] = array('id' => $id++, 'nome_torre' => 'Torre Norte', 'nome_bloco' => '', 'nome_apto' => 'Apto ' . $unidade, 'andar' => $andar);        
    }
}
for ( $andar = 1; $andar < 6; $andar++) { // Torre Sul
    for ( $unidade = ($andar * 100) + 1; $unidade < ($andar * 100) + 5; $unidade ++) {
        $rows[] = array('id' => $id++, 'nome_torre' => 'Torre Sul', 'nome_bloco' => '', 'nome_apto' => 'Apto ' . $unidade, 'andar' => $andar);      
    }
}

echo '<table><tr>';
for ($i = 0; $i < $cols; $i++ ) {
    echo sprintf('<th><input type="checkbox" id="col%d" onclick="toogleUnidades(\'col%1$d\');"/>Selecionar Unidades Final %d</th>', $i, $i+1);
}
echo '<tr></tr>';
// O código abaixo só existe no exemplo
// Remover - Inicio 
$row = reset($rows);
            $nome_torre_old = $row['nome_torre'];
            $nome_bloco_old = $row['nome_bloco'];
            $andar_old      = $row['andar'];
// Remover - Fim

// A linha abaixo no código final será for ($i = 1; $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); $i++ ) {    
for ($i = 0; $row = array_shift($rows); $i++ ) {
        if ($nome_torre_old != $row['nome_torre'] OR 
            $nome_bloco_old != $row['nome_bloco'] OR
            $andar_old      != $row['andar']) {
            echo '</tr><tr>';
            $nome_torre_old = $row['nome_torre'];
            $nome_bloco_old = $row['nome_bloco'];
            $andar_old      = $row['andar'];
        }
        $class = 'col' . ($i % $cols);
        echo sprintf('<td><input class="chk %s" style="margin-left:20px;" type="checkbox" id="p%d" name="p%2$d" %s />%s %s %s</td>', 
            $class, 
            $row['id'], 
//          ($row['plt_uni_in_id_unidade']== $row['id'] AND $row['plt_uni_in_id_planta'] == $id_work ? 'checked="checked"' : ''),
            '',
            $row['nome_torre'],
            $row['nome_bloco'],
            $row['nome_apto']
            );
}
echo '</tr></table>';           
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toogleUnidades(id) {
        var st = $("#" + id).is(":checked");        
        $("." + id).each(function(){
            this.checked = st;
        });
    }

</script>
```

Explicando alguns trechos:

- No sprintf usei notações %2$d que indica que deve ser substituído pelo segundo argumento da lista de *replaces* como um decimal
- No javascript criei um checkbox para a coluna com um id e adicionei a classe com esse mesmo nome de id para os elementos dessa coluna, dessa forma posso usar a seleção de todos os elementos com o mesmo nome de classe